# Is it "ok" to reset iPhones for use in a user test and setup Apple ID again afterwards?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, apple-id

This may seem as a quite stupid question, but I'm really unsure about this.

I own two iPhones (6 and 8) which we would like to use in an App test.

As I don't want the participants to have access to everything connected to my Apple ID, for obvious reasons, I would like to reset the devices as for a sale.

What I'm unsure about is:

- Could there be a problem because that might seem as a unusual behaviour which could lock me out / prevent registering them afterwards again, or a more severe consequence of locking me out of the Apple ID itself?
- Can I just use a reset device for installing Apps over XCode (they are registered as devices for development)? --> this I can just try for myself, but as I am asking anyway...

I found the possibility to temporary deactivate my Apple ID which isn't what I want as I still need my Macbook.

Comment: The answer for the first question is ***yes***. For the second, I'm not sure but I think it's the same.

Comment: I don’t do dev work, but I have 4 Apple IDs - one personal and 3 others for sys admin and testing work.  I’ve never had an issue.